# How to upload file directly to MVC4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, upload

I have this MVC4 web application that does CRUD actions for my database. Now I need to upload log files from native mobile application to database. Since it upload log file directly from mobile application code, it does not use RAZOR web page. I'm not sure how to set controller parameter to accept log file. Please give me some hint!

Comment: What do you mean by "directly from mobile application code"? Are you making a HTTP request with a `multipart/form-data` request, or does the raw request body contain the uploaded file?

Comment: My mobile application normally get() xml data from web-application, and I use post parameter to do such activity. This time I want to upload a log file to the same server and I'm lost where to begin.